# Android json parse not working

Tags: android, json

I have put a url

```
private static String url = "http://10.50.101.27:8090/AndroidApp/downloads/result.json";
```

and tried to parse using json parser in android but it is not working.

My Json format given below:

```
{"userdetails":[{"address":"Thrissur","name":"Pramoj","userid":"user001"},{"address":"Trivandrum","name":"Santhosh","userid":"user002"}]}
```

How can I parse. The json parse not responding. Please help me.

Comment: Show ur parsed code what you tried

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("userdetails");
for (i = 0; i < jArray.length();i++){
  JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  oneObject.getString("address");//return the address
  oneObject.getString("name");//return the name
  oneObject.getString("userid");//return the userId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all convert thr `response string` from your `server` to a **JSONObject** `since its structure is a JSONObject.` And then get the `JSONArray userdetails` from that `JSONObject`. **Loop** through that array and get the `JSONObject's` at each individual position. Afterwards get the necessary `strings(address,name,userid)` fron that `JSONObject.`

Example code snippet follows..

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

JSONArray jArr = obj.getJSONArray("userdetails");

for(int i=0; i < jArr.length(); i++)
{
      JSONObject jObj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);

      Log.v("address",jObj.getString("address").trim());

      Log.v("name",jObj.getString("name").trim());

      Log.v("userid",jObj.getString("userid").trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void parseJson(String jsonString)
{
    try
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray userdetails = json.getJSONArray("userdetails");
        for (int i=0; i<userdetails.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject user = userdetails.getJSONObject(i);
            String address = user.getString("address");
            String name = user.getString("name");
            String userid = user.getString("userid");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: Problem occured because my IP address is not global!!

Answer (score 0):

JSONParser class  :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

And the parsing code  :

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {
    // Getting Array of userdetails
    userdetails = json.getJSONArray("userdetails");

    // looping through All userdetails
    for(int i = 0; i < userdetails.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = userdetails.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing each json item in variable
        String id = c.getString("userid");
        String name = c.getString("name");
        String address = c.getString(address);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

url="your json url"

```
    public class Uploadfilechecking extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Activity mcontext;
    String username, password;
    boolean checkbox_value;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String JSONResp;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String Success_msg;

    private JSONArray tmp;

    private View progressView;
    private Object fileUploadManager;
    protected WeakReference<Context> context;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            URL u = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Read the stream
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while (is.read(b) != -1)
                baos.write(b);

            JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return JSONResp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println("filecheckresult" + result);
        try {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray array=obj.getJSONArray("userdetails");


               for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject actor = array.getJSONObject(i);
                   System.out.println(actor.getString("address"));
            }


        }catch(JSONException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray arr = jObj.getJSONArray("userdetails");
for (int i = 0; i < arr .length();i++){
 JSONObject innerobject = arr .getJSONObject(i);
innerobject.getString("address");
innerobject.getString("name");
innerobject.getString("userid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create class and getter/setter for userdetails

```
    public class userdetails {
      private String name, address, userid;
    }
```

Create sink class

```
      public class Sink {
          List<userdetails> userdetails;
      }
```

Call that response to sink

```
   List<userdetails>user_details= new ArrayList<userdetails>();
   SinkItem datas = new Gson().fromJson(response, SinkItem.class);
     user_details= datas.userdetails;
```

import Gson library to libs folder

Answer (score 0):

***JSON Helper Class***

```
public class JSONHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    String myUrl;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    OnAsyncLoader onAsyncLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap;
    JSONObject hashMapWithJson;
    boolean isProgressVisible;


    public JSONHelper(Context context, String url, HashMap<String, String> hashMap, OnAsyncLoader onAsynckLoader, boolean isProgressVisible) {
        this.context = context;
        myUrl = url;
        this.onAsyncLoader = onAsynckLoader;
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
        this.isProgressVisible = isProgressVisible;
    }

    public JSONHelper(Context context, String url, HashMap<String, String> hashMap, OnAsyncLoader onAsynckLoader, boolean isProgressVisible, JSONObject jsonObj) {
        this.context = context;
        myUrl = url;
        this.onAsyncLoader = onAsynckLoader;
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
        this.isProgressVisible = isProgressVisible;
        this.hashMapWithJson = jsonObj;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (isProgressVisible) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            if(Constants.hashMap.containsKey("nop.progressdilog.title"))
                progressDialog.setMessage(Constants.hashMap.get("nop.progressdilog.title"));
            else
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait a moment");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (context!=null) {
                Log.d("JSON_HELPER", url.toString());
            }

            if (hashMap != null) {
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                Log.d("LOGDATA", writer.toString());
                writer.write(getPostDataString(hashMap));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            }
            if (hashMapWithJson != null) {
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(hashMapWithJson.toString());

        /*OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(hashMapWithJson.toString());*/
//        writer.write(getPostDataString(hashMap));

                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
//        os.close();
            }
            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (isProgressVisible) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        try {
            onAsyncLoader.OnResult(s);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

}
```