# how to get json in android?

Tags: php, android, json, arrays

***First question.*** php echos json data like this

```
             echo(json_encode($thing));
```

then how can i get this json data in android??

do i have to use JSONArray, JSONObject?

***Second question.*** if php echos String data, then how can i convert this String data to JSON data?
 i tried httpPost in android using asynctask and it gets the String data from php.

```
String get_url = null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
get_url = sendData("music", "http://www.test.com/test.php");

private String sendData(String name, String url)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpPost request = makeHttpPost(name, url);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler<String> reshandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String result = client.execute(request, reshandler);
        return result;
    }

    private HttpPost makeHttpPost(String name, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        Vector<NameValuePair> nameValue = new Vector<NameValuePair>();
        nameValue.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        request.setEntity(makeEntity(nameValue));
        return request;
    }

    private HttpEntity makeEntity(Vector<NameValuePair> nameValue) {
        HttpEntity result = null;
        try {
            result = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValue);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Here is a guide : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: please see the below link what i have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212520/android-json-parse-not-working/20212854#20212854 (to read json data from url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, here is an example of parsing json in Android :

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject jObj;
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    Log.v("debug", "JSON ready to parsing");
    return jObj;
}

public void parsingData(JSONObject json) {
    try {
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            // Do your stuff, example :
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            title = c.getString("title");                
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("debug", "Error during the connection HTTP");
        cancel(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first qus's answer 
here u will get example for json parsing 
https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-json-parsing-url-example.html

now 2nd question's answer may be this

EDIT: You need your java Data class to be an exact model of the JSON. So your

```
{"data":{"translations":[{"translatedText":"Bonjour tout le monde"}]}}
```

becomes:

```
class DataWrapper {
    public Data data;

    public static DataWrapper fromJson(String s) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(s, DataWrapper.class);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}
class Data {
    public List<Translation> translations;
}
class Translation { 
    public String translatedText;
}
```

As the object model gets more complicated the org.json style code veers towards unreadable whereas the gson/jackson style object mapping is still just plain java objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

[1](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/): https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ .

how to use it:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/